# Flutter Hot Reload and Hot Restart not working

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to work on a project that I just started and while editing the app I realized that **neither hot reload nor hot restart are working** even though I have changed the design multiple times. The only time that I would see a change in the screen is when I **uninstall the app and run again**,

I am testing the app on an emulator and I am using Android Studio.

I searched for a solution before typing this question and this is what I have tried:

- flutter clean
- flutter doctor -v **then** flutter upgrade
- deleting the emulator and trying on another emulator
- invalidate cache and restart

It used to work really well and now it is not, here's an example:

```
import 'package:gradient_app_bar/gradient_app_bar.dart';

import '../constants.dart';

class PlantScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlantScreenState createState() => _PlantScreenState();
}

class _PlantScreenState extends State<PlantScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GradientAppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('plant A'),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: Constants.primaryGradient,
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight),
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: Constants.primaryVariantGradient,
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I figured the issue was with my import statement

it was :

`import 'file:///E:/SelfProjects2/water_my_plants/lib/screens/plantScreen.dart';`

I have changed it to

`import 'package:water_my_plants/screens/plantScreen.dart';`

in my main dart file that had the route to the PlantScreen()

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped. Additionnaly, I can say that this happens import statement failure happens on refactoring. So you guys should be careful when you move files around :)

Comment: saved my day, tnx

Answer (score 0):

In my Linux machine, I configured the

```
http_proxy
https_proxy
proxy
no_proxy
```

environment variables. Then I was able to use hot reload and restart.