# Cant do Hot-reload or Hot-restart after I clicked flutter attach button

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, proxy

Everything was working fine for my app till I clicked on **Flutter-attach** button in my Android Studio, after I did so, I got these logs:

```
Waiting for a connection from Flutter on Android SDK built for x86...
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56545/cddwLNAgzFM=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
```

then the hot-reload & hot restart stopped to work completely!
When I click on any of them, the app restarts but no changes occur!

I don't have any Environment Variables, and my proxy settings are set to No Proxy

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

When I do a hot restart, the app restarts successfully at the home page, but without any change to it!

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 3,188ms.
```

Comment: Have you checked the log of `flutter run -v`? And you also need to check your computer specifications.

Comment: I checked the ```flutter run -v``` but I didnt find anything... 
what should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was never with the proxies or flutter attach, but it was with my import at the main screen (Probably this happened after I removed some paths at the start of the android studio).

it was:

```
import 'file:///F:/Users/user1/StudioProjects/project1/lib/screens/new_articles/zoom_images_screen.dart';
```

and I changed it to:

```
import 'package:project1/lib/screens/new_articles/zoom_images_screen.dart';
```

and it worked!
I found the solution at this post [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167373/flutter-hot-reload-and-hot-restart-not-working)